# Is there a way to nest sections without producing empty lines in a Mustache template?

Tags: mustache

Consider this: `foo = false` and `bar = true`.

I'd like to render the following template:

```
{{#foo}}{{#bar}} Both foo and bar are true {{/bar}}{{/foo}}
{{^foo}}{{#bar}} foo is false, bar is true {{/bar}}{{/foo}}
{{#foo}}{{^bar}} foo is true, bar is false {{/bar}}{{/foo}}
```

Expected output:

```
foo is false, bar is true
```

But it renders:

```
// empty line here
foo is false, bar is true
// empty line here
```

Is there a way to nest sections without producing empty lines?